# ¿como solucionar el error System.OutOfMemoryException en asp.net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con esto ya que me genera una excepción y no se a que se deba.

Estoy leyendo un archivo y después lo guardo como este ejemplo.

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-File-without-clicking-Submit-Button-using-FileUpload-control-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Despues se ejecuta mi webMethod para mostrar la información en un jqxGrid. Tengo un archivo de 3,137 filas el cual lo muestra correcto pero tengo otro archivo que subo el cual contiene 15,000 filas y ahí es donde me saca esta excepción

Este es el error que me saca:

```
{"Message":"Se produjo una excepción de tipo \u0027System.OutOfMemoryException\u0027.","StackTrace":"   en System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)\r\n   en System.Text.StringBuilder.GetNewString(String currentString, Int32 requiredLength)\r\n   en System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char value)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeString(String input, StringBuilder sb)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.OutOfMemoryException"}

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
at Object.error (Archivo_Excel.js:89)
at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Este es mi webMethod

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Importar_Excel()
    {
        Transacciones t = new Transacciones();
        string dir_archivo = HttpContext.Current.Session["fileLocation"].ToString();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ExcelToDataTable(dir_archivo);
        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
        return datos;
    }
```

Comment: No puedes convertir un datatable a json, si tienes un archivo deberias convertirlo a una `List<>` en base a una class que definas con los datos para luego serializar

Comment: cargar una grid web con 15mil rows no sirve para nada, deberias poder volcar esto en una db y poder paginar los datos

Comment: Si es un archivo comun , solo exponlo en una carpeta para descargarlo.